# Left margin doesn't work on left-aligned button in Outlook 2016

Tags: html-email

I am developing an HTML email and trying to provide a left margin for my left aligned button. It works on other email clients but not on Outlook 2016. Here is my code:

```html
<tr>
  <td valign="top" align="left" style="text-align:left;padding:10px 40px 10px 40px">
    <!-- CTA Button : BEGIN -->
      <center>
        <table role="presentation" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="text-align:center">
          <tr>
            <td style="border-radius:50px;background:#EEB123;text-align:center" class="button-td">
              <div class="mktoText" id="splash-cta-button" mktoName="CTA Button">
                <a href="#" style="background:#EEB123;border:15px solid #EEB123;font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:20px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;display:block;border-radius:5px;font-weight:500;text-transform:uppercase" class="button-a" target="_BLANK">
                  <span style="color:#FFFFFF" class="button-link">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Click Here!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                 </a>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </cente>
    <!-- CTA Button : END -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

J.

Comment: You can use table columns instead of padding if you don't plan on changing it. Or you can break the padding values to be individuals example: `padding-top`, `padding-right` etc

Answer (score 0):

Outlooks will not regard block styles on inline elements, even if you try and change them using `display:block`.

Thus, you need to put any padding on a native block element, typically the `<td>`. Margins are not cross-email-compatible so do use padding.

Furthermore, this is email, so for cross-email-compatibility, you should be inlining the styles instead of using classes (except for mobiles where you'll want to use @media).

I.e wrap your table in another table, and use the `<td>` to insert the padding:

```
<center>
<table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" style="padding-left:15px">
        <table role="presentation" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="text-align:center">
          <tr>
            <td style="border-radius:50px;background:#EEB123;text-align:center" class="button-td">
              <div class="mktoText" id="splash-cta-button" mktoName="CTA Button">
                <a href="#" style="background:#EEB123;border:15px solid #EEB123;font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:20px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;display:block;border-radius:5px;font-weight:500;text-transform:uppercase" class="button-a" target="_BLANK">
                  <span style="color:#FFFFFF" class="button-link">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Click Here!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                 </a>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
      </center>
```